# Spring Integration xpath expression Multiple Condition Check

Tags: spring, xpath, spring-integration

I have an SAP IDOC that I want to filter but I am Stuck at one Place.

Here is a Sample XML

```
    <E1EDK14 SEGMENT="1">
        <QUALF>007</QUALF>
        <ORGID>10</ORGID>
    </E1EDK14>
    <E1EDK14 SEGMENT="1">
        <QUALF>008</QUALF>
        <ORGID>BP01</ORGID>
    </E1EDK14>
    <E1EDK14 SEGMENT="1">
        <QUALF>012</QUALF>
        <ORGID>ZMOR</ORGID>
    </E1EDK14>
```

The Condition would be Something like

if QUALF = 12 and ORGID = ZOR then process else ignore

My Code is Something like this

```
<int-xml:xpath-router id="splitORGID" input-channel="ORDERS" evaluate-as-string="true" resolution-required="false" default-output-channel="ORDER-TYPE-NOT-SUPPORTED">
    <int-xml:xpath-expression id="splitORGIDExpression" expression="//E1EDK14/ORGID" />
    <int-xml:mapping value="ZOR" channel="ALLOW_ORDERS" />
</int-xml:xpath-router>
```

I would like to know if this is correct.

Comment: I know nothing about spring integration, but XPath expression to select `E1EDK14` element where child `QUALF` = 12 and `ORGID` = ZMOR would be : `//E1EDK14[QUALF=12 and ORGID='ZMOR']`

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your Answer.I am basically new to XPATH so from the Expression //EIEDK14[QUALF=12] doesn't it mean take QUALF attribute rather than the Child node. So that would be something like         <EIEDK14   QUALF="12">/<EIEDK14>

Comment: No. Attribute is referenced using `@` in XPath, like `//E1EDK14[@SEGMENT=1]`

Comment: Hi Sorry for the Delayed Response So it's finally working now.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Solution I came up with and it is working fine

```
<int-xml:xpath-router id="splitORGID" input-channel="CUSTORDERS" evaluate-as-string="true" resolution-required="false" default-output-channel="ORDERTYPE-NOTSUPPORTED-KTOKD">
    <int-xml:xpath-expression id="splitORGIDExpression" expression="//E1EDK14[QUALF=012]/ORGID" />
    <int-xml:mapping value="ZOR" channel="ORDERS" />
    <int-xml:mapping value="ZSCO" channel="ORDERS" />
    <int-xml:mapping value="ZMOR" channel="HISTORICALORDERS" />
</int-xml:xpath-router>
```